# Java .parallelStream() with spring annotated methods

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, java-8, java-stream

I try using the `parallelStream()` in DAO with Spring `@Transactional` annotations and get so problem:

```
@Transactional
public void processCollection(Collection<Object> objects) {
    objects.parallelStream()
            .forEach(this::processOne);  //throw exception
}

@Transactional
public void processOne(Object o) {
    ...
}
```

Works correct:

```
@Transactional
public void processCollection(Collection<Object> objects) {
    objects.stream()
            .forEach(this::processOne);  //work correctly
}

@Transactional
public void processOne(Object o) {
    ...
}
```

Exception:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:106)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:978)
```

How can I use `@Transactional` annotated methods by `parallelStream()`?

**Update**
Why this happen [Spring transaction manager and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835974/spring-transaction-manager-and-multithreading)
But I hope spring 4 with java 8 support can provide some solution for this. Any ideas?

Comment: A trivial question, but do you get the same error if you use stream().parallel()?

Comment: Yes, I have the same problem with  stream().parallel()

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835974/spring-transaction-manager-and-multithreading

Comment: Thank you Evgeni, I understand why this happen. Work around for this is interesting.

Comment: I am wondering why would you like to have @Transactional on processCollection when you want to run it in parallel.

Comment: It's just example, What if it will '@Cacheable' instance of '@Transactional' ? Cache will work for only one thread as I understand..

Answer (score 10):

Well, I have a guess consists of several guesses:

- You have session management policy as `session-per-thread`;
- `Object` you wrote in example is in fact some entity that uses lazy loading;
- `processOne()` method uses entity properties that are loaded lazily;
- Because of first point, threads, started for `parallelStream()` has no session available (probably in `ThreadLocal`, don't remember how technically sessions are bound to threads);

That altogether causing the problem you have. The behavior looks quite strange to me, so I suggest to do the following:

- Remove all lazy loading and try `parallelStream()` again;
- If that succeeds, you'll have to load the entities completely before performing `parallelStream()`.

Alternative way to go: detaching all list elements from session before doing `parallelStream()`.

Although as Marko wrote in comments, `Session` is not thread-safe, so that means you have to get rid of `Session` usage either by removing lazy loading, or by detaching all entities from session.

Comment: Hibernate's session is not thread-safe. The only option is detachment.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is not with parallel stream. In spring transaction is created using AOP.
When your processCollection method is executed spring create a proxy object of this and transaction is started.
Calling another method in same class, spring will not run that method in New transaction even if you specified @Transaction .
To get it run move that method process() to new service and then execute your problem. Your program will work fine.