# Spring @Async: null hibernate session on LAZY collection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-session

I'm using an `@Async` annotation on a service layer method.

Everything works fine when I EAGERLY load @OneToMany collection fields, but when I try to access LAZY loaded element I found that Hibernate `SessionImplementor` object `session` is null. That obviously give me an exception:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role:
....
```

Here is my collection field:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="abc", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)
@OrderBy(value="xsd asc")
@JsonIgnore
private Set<Item> items = new HashSet<Item>();
```

How can I bind hibernate session in order to LAZELY load my object inside `@Async` context?

**EDIT**

Here is my trancactionManager / entityManager configuration

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter">

    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="it.domain"/>

    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy</prop>
            <!--${hibernate.format_sql} -->
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            <!-- ${hibernate.show_sql} -->
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop> 

            <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">20</prop>

            <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix">_H</prop>
            <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.revision_field_name">AUDIT_REVISION</prop>
            <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.revision_type_field_name">ACTION_TYPE</prop>
            <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy">org.hibernate.envers.strategy.ValidityAuditStrategy</prop>
            <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy_validity_end_rev_field_name">AUDIT_REVISION_END</prop>
            <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy_validity_store_revend_timestamp">True</prop>
            <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy_validity_revend_timestamp_field_name">AUDIT_REVISION_END_TS</prop>               
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<jpa:repositories base-package="it.repository"
                  entity-manager-factory-ref="emf"
                  transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"/>

<jpa:auditing auditor-aware-ref="auditorAwareBean" />
<bean id="auditorAwareBean" class="it.auditor.AuditorAwareBean"/>
```

Comment: Are you using a Spring managed SessionFactory and TransactionManager?. Can you show the code of the method?

Comment: Is the method _loading_ the entity or just accessing it?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, the method load the entity calling corresponding repository

Comment: The JPA and Hibernate transaction managers work almost the same... I just updated my answer. In any case, if you remove the @Async annotation it should work... but I believe you don't want this.

Comment: @ElderMael I know that withous Async it works :) The problem is with Async ;)

Comment: In that case you may implement a [CurrentSessionContext](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/context/spi/CurrentSessionContext.html) that allows you to preserve sessions across threads and calling threads.

Comment: It's not that difficult, the difficult part is that you will manage the sessions and threads.

Comment: @gipinani I just updated the question with that info.

Comment: I had same issue when I was using @async. I tried a lot of things and finally dealt with it by opening a new session and doing stuff and then closing the session. I am not sure if it is an ideal solution, but given the fact that hibernate session and thread have some personal issues on being  together, I am happy with this solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Spring's transaction context is preserved using [ThreadLocals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html). This means that your SessionFactory is only available to the thread dispatching your request thus, if you create a new thread, you will get a `null` and a corresponding exception.

What your `@Async` method does is use a [TaskExecutor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/TaskExecutor.html) to run your method in another thread. So the problem described above is happening with your service.

I quote from the Spring's [JpaTransactionManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/JpaTransactionManager.html) docs:

> PlatformTransactionManager implementation for a single JPA
>   EntityManagerFactory. **Binds a JPA EntityManager from the specified
>   factory to the thread**, potentially allowing for one thread-bound
>   EntityManager per factory. SharedEntityManagerCreator and
>   @PersistenceContext are aware of thread-bound entity managers and
>   participate in such transactions automatically. Using either is
>   required for JPA access code supporting this transaction management
>   mechanism.

If you want to preserve your annotation then you should take a look at Hibernate [CurrentSessionContext](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/context/spi/CurrentSessionContext.html) and somehow manage the sessions yourself.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835974/spring-transaction-manager-and-multithreading) for more info.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem, spent few days trying to find a solution, finally got a solution. I would like to share the details I found for those who might have the same issue.

1st - Your `@Async`-annotated method should be declared in a separate bean rather than the `@Controller`- or `@RestController`-annotated bean.

2nd - You certainly need to declare the method `@Transactional` which is called from within `@Async` declared method. However, the very first method called from `@Async` method has to be defined `@Transactional`. I had the `@Transactional` method in second or third level in the method execution stack therefore the problem was not solved and I spent two days trying to figure out what was going on.

So the best thing to do is

```
@Controller
ControllerBean {

    @Autowired
    AsyncService asyncService;

    public controllerMethod() {
        asyncService.asyncMethod();
    }
}

@Service
AsyncService {
    @Autowired
    TransactionalService transactionalService;

    @Async
    public asyncMethod() {
        transactionalService.transactionalMethod();
    }
}

@Service
TransactionalService {
    @Autowired
    SomeOtherService someOtherService;

    @Autowired
    EntityRepository entityRepository;

    @Transactional
    public transactionalMethod() {
        Entity entity = entityRepository.findOne(12345);

        someOtherService.doWork(entity);
    }
}

@Service
SomeOtherService {

    @Autowired
    EntityRepository entityRepository;

    @Transactional
    public doWork(Entity entity) {
        // fetch lazy properties, save, etc. without any session problems...
        entity.getLazyProperties(); 

        entityRepository.save(entity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In normal circumstances (without `@Async`) a transaction gets propagated through the call hierarchy from one Spring component to the other.

When a `@Transactional` Spring `@Component` calls a method annotated with `@Async` this does not happen. The call to the asynchronous method is being scheduled and executed at a later time by a task executor and is thus handled as a 'fresh' call, i.e. without a transactional context. If the `@Async` method (or the component in which it is declared) is not `@Transactional` by itself Spring will not manage any needed transactions.

Try to annotate the method that calls the `@Async` method, and tell us if worked.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My methos is already transactional!

Answer (score 0):

It depends how and where does a mapping occur.

If you want to use **@Async** together with **LAZY** loading, a method declared with **@Transactional** has to implement the logic of **LAZY** loading.

If **LAZY** loading is initated outside **@Transactional**, it will not work.