# Hibernate is not loading the data from DB in new thread {org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet}

Tags: java, multithreading, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm using spring boot with hibernate. When I try to load the data(from PostgreSQL) in the new thread, hibernate is giving an exception. However, it's working fine if I'm executing the code in a single thread. Below is the snippet for this.

Customer.java

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<UserEntity> entityList = new ArrayList<UserEntity>();
}
```

UserEntity.java

```
@Entity
public class UserEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Customer customer;
}
```

Service layer

```
public class EmailServiceImpl {

    public void someFunction() {
        Customer cus = customerRepo.findOne(1l);
        new Thread(() -> {
            cus.getEntityList().isEmpty(); // Below mentioned exception is pointing to this line
            // executing some operations based on the size of above list
        }).start();
    }

}
```

Exception/error when trying to execute the above method

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:434) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:186) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:121) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:688) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1991) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:570) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:252) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:566) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:135) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$1.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:164) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$1.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:252) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:148) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.isEmpty(PersistentBag.java:266) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at com.e2log.service.impl.EmailServiceImpl.lambda$3(EmailServiceImpl.java:505) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This statement has been closed.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.checkClosed(PgStatement.java:649) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.getMaxRows(PgStatement.java:485) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.createResultSet(PgStatement.java:158) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement$StatementResultHandler.handleResultRows(PgStatement.java:210) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2092) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:288) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:430) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:356) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:168) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:116) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor144.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy215.executeQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
```

Scenarios in which code is executing, but which is not suitable for me

1. Single threaded execution (i.e commenting/removing the 2 lines `new Thread(() -> {` and `}).start();` )
2. Loading the data eagerly (i.e changing the line `@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)` to `@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)` in `Customer.java`)

   3. Writing the line `cus.getEntityList().isEmpty();` or `cus.getEntityList().size();` above the line `new Thread(() -> {`. (I think hibernate is loading the data if we are trying to find the size before start iof the new thread)

Is there any way to make the concurrent code work, without using Eager loading?

FYI,
Spring boot version: 1.5.10.RELEASE
Java: 1.8
PostgreSQL: 9.5

Comment: No that is not possible as `Transactions` are tied to threads

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring @Async: null hibernate session on LAZY collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25083295/spring-async-null-hibernate-session-on-lazy-collection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transactional context used by Spring is stored in a thread-local variable. So if you start a new thread, or execute code in another thread using a callable, this code won't be part of the transaction started by the Spring transactional aspect.

Instead if you want to process something Async with some data pulled from DB, then you should first load Data from DB into a variable, and then pass that loaded data to the Async thread for further processing.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. Is there any way to override the default transactional context, like extending the context and using it for multiple threads?

Comment: No, I do not think it is possible to extend context to multiple threads, there is nice example explaining how it works [here](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-transaction-management-over-multiple-thread-1)