# LazyInitializationException occuring post introducing @Controller Annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, lazy-initialization

We have a distributed web application implemented in Spring using Method Name Resolver. We are now migrating from Method Name Resolver to Spring Annotation (@Controller). Once we did that change, the big issue that we are facing is all the LAZY Initialization is not working. We started getting the below error:

```
2020-11-10 13:12:53,678 DEBUG     o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet:1182 Handler execution resulted in exception - forwarding to resolved error view: ModelAndView: reference to view with name 'XXXXXXXX'; model is {XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.17.Final.jar:4.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.17.Final.jar:4.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.17.Final.jar:4.2.17.Final]
```

On Analysis, we are able to find that, with the Method Name Resolver, System was able to Lazy Initialize the object. While in the @Controller annotation, System throws the LazyInitializationError, since the Session object is getting closed and not able to lazily initialize.

What could be the solution to overcome this? how to maintain the session through with the @Controller similar to Method name resolver.

Any insights will be highly apprecitated. Thanks.

Comment: you can try annotation @Transactional at method that call lazyload onbject collections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are using the "Open Session In View" (anti-)pattern. Look at Spring's `OpenSessionInViewFilter`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your controller method is asynchronous. If that's the case there would be no session as the call is done in a different thread and the session doesn't come along with it. This [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25083295/spring-async-null-hibernate-session-on-lazy-collection) explains that and has a solution.
Check if your controller method have an @Async annotation or something similar. If that's the case, it would definitely throw that error.