# NPE when collecting from parallel stream

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, parallel-processing, java-stream

I have a list of around 40,000 objects on average (it bumps upto 80K at most) wrapped in Spring `Page`

```
Page<People> people = //loaded data using PeopleRepository of "People" entity
```

Then generating a map to export the records in excel file

```
List<Map<String, String>> excelData = Streams.batches(people, 500)
            .parallel()
            .map(PageImple::new) //Converting each chunk in a page
            .map(this::buildDTO) // Creating DTO objects from people entities
            .map(Slice::getContent)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .map(this::buildExportData)
            .collect(                    <----
                Collectors.toList()
             );
```

Above piece of code sporadically throws the following NPE. It is thrown from core java library. Anyone can give any hint what might be causing the issue? Is it related to parallem stream? Do I need any other mechanism for parallel streaming?

Exception

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:598)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.invoke(ForkJoinTask.java:735)
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateParallel(ReduceOps.java:714)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:233)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
```

On a different but similar scenario I also observed the following exception,

```
    org.hiberate.AssertionFailure: bug adding collection twice
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.addCollection(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:851)
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.addInitializedConnection(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:890)
         // -- Will add remaiing part of the stack trace if required.
```

**Edit 2 (breaking news!)**
We found this same behaviour in two places. They both have one common line, loading a relationship from using Lazy fetching. The entity confir looks like below,

```
@ManyToMany(fetch=Fetch.Lazy)
@JoinTable(.. ... ...)
private Set<Classification> classifications
```

Is there anything going wrong using parallel stream with Lazy fetching?

**Edit 1**
After some more investigation, if I look at `java.util.concurrent.ForkJointTask line#291`, the code looks like below,

```
try {
    completed = exec();
} catch(Throwable rex) {
    return setExceptionalCompletion(rex);
}
```

Looks like it means it failed to execute one of the map block. Therefore, as @Eugene asked in the comment if it is the only stacktrace, answer is no. There is a **"Caused By"** section. Here it goes,

```
    Caused By: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.LoadContexts.cleanup(LoadContexts.java:81)
        at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:202)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.endLoading(CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.java:154)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishLoadingCollections(AbstractRowReader.java:249)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishUp(AbstractRowReader.java:212)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:123)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:122)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
        ...
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2004)
        ...
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
```

Comment: one of the mappings in your stream is returning null....

Comment: you sure that is the _entire_ stack trace?

Comment: @Eugene: Nope that is not the entire stacktrace. This is the top most section right after after the application code where `.collect(Collectors.toList())` is called.

Comment: Try breaking apart you stream to see which mapping fails... you need to be aware of what data might be null

Comment: @RobOhRob: Do you mean wither `buildDTO` or `buildExportData` is returning null for one or more records?

Comment: @Samiron it really could be any of them

Comment: trying doing something like this on your mappings to help debug `.map(obj -> {
 System.out.println("buildDto "+ (obj == null) )
 return this.buildDTO(obj);
}) `

Comment: @Eugene You asked if the stack trace has any other part or not. I edited my question, added the "Caused By" section.

Comment: @RobOhRob: a .`filter(Object::nonNull)` should handle that case right?

Comment: @Eugene I was just reading https://stackoverflow.com/q/37143082/1160106 seems related and you have some contribution there :)

Comment: @Samiron `filter(Object::nonNull)` should do the trick... but you would have to add it after each individual mapping call.... It'd be a better idea to figure out which specific mapping is returning a null and why... once you know that, then you can decide how best to handle

Comment: I made a solution based on the theory of issues when hibernate session used in multithreaded env. Lets see if that fixes the problem. I will get back with update.

Comment: @Eugene The problem was indeed using hibernate session in multithreading context. Would you mind add an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @Samiron sorry, it's too thin for an answer, glad you got it sorted it though.

Comment: Oh no! I just missed my two cents :) kidding... Thanks @Eugene